# Get the Phone Number from Dynamic crm online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to dynamic CRM. I have requirement to pass the contact info to webservice. when the user clicks on the phone number, instead of triggering call through skype or lync, I need to pass the contact information(Phone number,Contact name) to my web service.Please guide me to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

Using plugin and something similar to this

https://mscrmmindfire.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/calling-external-web-service-from-a-crm-2011-plug-in/

Comment: This is not helpful.. how to do i get the info on dialing a phone number?

Comment: Ach sorry, than you need to use javascript